# fatal: unable to connect to github.com: github.com[0: 140.82.121.4]: errno=Unknown error

Tags: git, git-push, git-remote

I'm having a problem with my Git account. Every time I execute `git push`, I get the following error:

[image: Git push error]

I discovered that I'm working with an SSH URL:

[image: SSH URL]

I tried switching back to an HTTPS URL using the following commands:

```
git config --global url.https://github.com/.insteadOf git://github.com/
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

However, it doesn't seem to change anything:
[image: example]

I tried many options that I thought were solutions such as manually configuration of config file but nothing works.

Answer (score 74):

This error occurred because your **git port is restricted**. 
So you can get it fixed with the following command:

```
git config --global url.https://github.com/.insteadOf git://github.com/
```

By doing this globally it will also repair other issues where perhaps old repositories or other scenarios may be using `git` instead of `https` when the `git://` port/protocol may not be functional now vs earlier.

Please upvote if it worked for you!
Thank you.

Comment: Very helpful succinct answer, thank you. In my case I was having an odd issue with old `Sublime Text 3` packages failing to update. It turns out that when they were installed they used the `git://` protocol vs `https://` and now no longer update and cause various hangs and peculiar problems with Sublime Text.

Answer (score 4):

To use `git` with `ssh`, a different url syntax is needed, with `git@<url>` as url.
According to your screenshot, the url should most likely look like this

```
git@github.com:ahlemtbini/blog_web.git
```

You can change it with the following command

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:ahlemtbini/blog_web.git
```

If you are using `github`, i recommend you to always use the url's listed under the `code`-button at the `github`-page of that repository. [More information here](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/cloning-a-repository)

For more information about protocols used by git, read the page about [git server protocols](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols).

Comment: no still working with ssh url  i run   git push -u origin main and this is the result 
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: Have you added your public key to your github profile and are you using the right ssh key while pushing? https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent and https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account

Answer (score 2):

So there's a few things going on here I think:

1. The error from your first screen shot looks like it may be caused by having cloned the repository using the plain `git://` protocol which doesn't do any type of authentication/authorization. Meaning you can `git pull` but you won't be able to `git push`.
2. If you want to update your git config to automatically use `https` when pushing, you can add something like this to your gitconfig:

```
[url "https://github.com/"]
    pushInsteadOf = git://github.com/
```

- assuming you have your [Personal Access Token cached](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/why-is-git-always-asking-for-my-password)

3. Alternatively if you want to use SSH instead of `git://` or `https://` protocol (and have your public key uploaded to your GH account) you can add

```
[url "git@github.com:"]
    pushInsteadOf = git://github.com/
    pushInsteadOf = https://github.com/
```

Comment: GitHub have also dropped support for the `git://` protocol, so it's a good idea to stop using such URLs. 

Answer (score 2):

I had this error while running `git submodule update --init`.

I fixed the problem by changing all my `git://` submodules to `https://` submodules in the `.gitmodules` file.

Then I ran

```
git submodule sync
```

After that my submodule update worked properly.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I figured out my flutter project was trying to fetch a dependency from an URL on the pubspec.yaml with the following format: "git:github.com/repository"...To fix it I just had to change the "git" for "https".