# Git connection problem. "fatal: unable to connect to github.com....."

Tags: windows, git, github, networking, repository

I have been having a problem with my git in so long, i have tried everything i could and it din't change anything.
My git works well locally, it works with init, commits, etc.
The problem is when i go to make whatever with github, since making a `git clone`, or `git push`
It doesn't work with either github CLI or Git Bash, or cmd.
Any of those commands i put in, just yield the following error:

```bash
fatal: unable to connect to github.com
github.com[0: 140.82.114.4]: errno=Unknown error

failed to run git: exit status 128
```

I've been trying with some internet solution perspectives:

- [This 26 upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72486457/fatal-unable-to-connect-to-github-com-github-com0-140-82-121-4-errno-unkno#:%7E:text=This%20error%20occurred%20because%20your%20git%20port%20is%20restricted.)
- [All this solutions](https://stackoverflow.com) about geting free port 9418, Trying with Https protocol, switching among ssh and https
- I revised `host` file in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` location for local DNS possible incorrect configuration
- I reinstalled Git
- I search for some network problems, and i have got `ping` from `github.com` server and `tracert github.com` command for viewing github request trace and it works good as well.
- I try using the following `culr` command to download the main branch zip file, through cmd and it WORKED, downloading the zip file!!!:

```bash
curl https://github.com/user/repo.git | git clone url:-
```

(of course, replacing my user and repo names)

- I configured git own proxy settings to `unset`:

```bash
git config --global --unset http.proxy
```

- I made github test for conection, obtaining good results against all servers ip and all other testing things.

I think that the problem is a git configuration realated with port or network, but i don't find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved the problem, i tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72486817/15180474) but in other way.
Adding this manually to the `.gitconfig` file, located within `%USERPROFILE%` directory:

```
[url "https://"]
    insteadOf = ssh://
    insteadOf = git://
```

because with the `cmd` commands:

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf ssh://
```

it was not setting up the configuration correctly.

I think what was happening is that git was trying to access GitHub via `ssh` and the port used for that protocol is 9418, which seemed to be blocked somehow. I discovered that using `netstat` tool from `cmd` which showed me the `SYN_SEND` state of the requests when i tried to do `git ls-remote`.
It is a patch solution, but it fixed it :(

Comment: Good catch, I see `git ls-remote` was useful.

Comment: yes it was, thank you so much, I have learnt a lot since I came to this site, everyday... beacuse of the vast knowledge here. Appreciate it and Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to check is the remote URL used for your repository.

Even without cloning, you can test the connectivity with:

```
# HTTP URL:
git ls-remote https://github.com/me/myrepo

# SSH URL:
git ls-remote git@github.com/me/myrepo
```

If one of them is working, use it to clone the repository.

Check also:

- for any environment variable related to Git or curl (type `set` in a CMD)
- for any proxy setting (again: `set|grep -i proxy`)
- for any PATH issue (try a [simplified PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75433297/6309) in a CMD for testing)